# SQL: MS Access DISTINCT for few columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

I have a table with 250 columns. I'm trying to Select all columns, but I want to use DISTINCT for two columns.

My begin it's sometihing like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT table_name.column_name FROM table_name).
```

But doesn't work.
Maybe somebody has any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have a table with 250 columns" -- have you considered that the difficultly you are having writing would would appear to be a simple query can be attributed to a design flaw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table_name tt 
                  WHERE tt.col1 = t.col1 
                    AND tt.col2 = t.col2 
                    AND tt.id > t.id)
```

Comment: I think your query is works. But I have a problem: for example in col2 is some NULL records and distinct don't work for the records where is NULL. Maybe I have to replace NULL to zero or something similar?

Comment: Replace `tt.col2 = t.col2` with `(tt.col2 IS NULL AND t.col2 IS NULL) OR (tt.col2 = t.col2)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can replace `tt.col2 = t.col2` with `ISNULL(tt.col2, 0) = ISNULL(t.col2, 0)`. Or you can use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is the primary Key of the Table,

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE col1 = t.col1 AND ID <> t.ID)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE col2 = t.col2 AND ID <> t.ID)
```

Comment: I don't now ms-access but will work `select *` with `group by`?

Comment: Have you tested this in MS Access? Did you not get an error about columns in the `SELECT` clause not appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: I got an error: Cannot group on on fields selected with '*'. Maybe it's an MS Access problem?

Comment: This won't work if we have two rows with same values in col1 and col2, but different ids: (id, col1, col2) - (1, "A", "B"), (2, "A", "B"). Your query will return empty response in this case. I think that this is not how DISTINCT should behave.

Comment: @DNNX please read the question carefully. He wanted to get all rows in the table where col1 & col2 are distinct! For the case you provided, empty response in the result Set is a desired output

Comment: @Akhil query works, but I get all rows. DISTINCT for col1, col2 don't go. All rows have different ID's. I want to get all rows in the table where col1 & col2 are distinct.